# Get the code name of a Class<Array>

Tags: java, reflection, code-generation

I'm doing some code generation using reflection and need to get the string describing certain array types in code. The default API doesn't really make this easy.

- `(new int[12]).getClass().getName()` returns `[I`
- `(new Date[2][]).getClass().getName()` returns `[[Ljava.util.Date`

The result is parseable, but is there an easier, nicer way to get `int[]` and `java.util.Date[][]` from those two, respectively?

Comment: `(new Integer[12]).getClass().getName()` returns "[Ljava.lang.Integer;"! `(new int[12]).getClass().getName()` returns "[I".

Comment: I think you mean "to get `int[]`" not "to get `Integer[]`".

Comment: To make the format nicer you would need to place some rules as you how you want it presented, like dropping "java.lang." or even "java.util." for List & Set. Don't forget that `java.sql.Date` is not the same as `java.util.Date`. ;)

Comment: @Matt: Yeah, same mistake as Joachim mentioned. @Peter: Since the code is generated, I don't care about FQN's in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>There's no built-in method that returns the "nice name" (a.k.a the name as written in Java source code),</strike>

[`getSimpleName()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSimpleName%28%29) returns the "nice" name: it returns only the class name without the package and appends `[]` as necessary.

If you need the fully-qualified names with `[]`, then you'd need to construct that manually:

```
 public static String getName(final Class<?> clazz) {
   if (!clazz.isArray()) {
     return clazz.getName();
   } else {
     return getName(clazz.getComponentType()) + "[]";
   }
 }
```

Comment: The OP probably wants `return clazz.getSimpleName()` instead of `return clazz.getName()`.

Comment: @Matt: Oops ... I didn't realize that `getSimpleName()` handles arrays as well! So my answer is actually wrong!

Comment: Since the code is generated, the fully qualified name is fine. But is there a way to get the array depth (e.g. `Date[][][]`) from the `Class` object?

Comment: @Bart: just call `getComponentType()` until `isArray()` returns `false` and count how many calls it takes: that's your array dimensions.

Answer (score 4):

Try [`Class.getSimpleName()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSimpleName%28%29).

> The simple name of an array is the simple name of the component type with "[]" appended.

Comment: Oh, very nice - I never noticed that before.